# JPQL query for datetime range ainst MS SQL Server table not working

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpql

```
String query = "select t.id from TheEntity t where t.registrationDate > :start and t.registrationDate > :end";
```

Given the simple query, I'm binding the following parameters:

```
q.setParameter("start", startDate);
q.setParameter("end", endDate);
```

startDate and endDate are both java.util.Date. When I log the parameters as they are bound to the query at runtime, it logs timestamps.

The problem, it returns no results, even thought sql returns data. What am I doing wrong? Should I just use strings?

Hibernate is the underlying implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use jpql, but this looks like your issue:
`t.registrationDate > :end`

is it supposed to be
`t.registrationDate < :end` or `t.registrationDate <= :end` 
instead ?